# Shapes not showing up

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to make some shapes filled with colors. The shapes doesn't show up!

Somebody Help Please!

I have two classes "menu.java" and "draw.java"

Here is my code for the "menu.java"

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class menu {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame JF = new JFrame("Menu Bar");
    JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    draw DR = new draw();
    JF.add(DR);
    JF.setSize(500,300);
    JF.setVisible(true);
    JF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }
}
```

The code for "draw.java"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class draw extends JPanel{
public void painComponent(Graphics GPHCS){
    super.paintComponent(GPHCS);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


    GPHCS.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    GPHCS.fillRect(25,25,100,30);

    GPHCS.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    GPHCS.fillRect(25,65,100,30);

    GPHCS.setColor(new Color(190,81,215));

    GPHCS.drawString("This is my text", 25, 120);
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot after running the program

[image]

Why does the shapes not showing up?!

Any answers would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is called `paintComponent`, not `painComponent`. So the method `paintComponent` does not get overridden as intended.

Use `@Override` tag before method to get notified of errors like these.

Comment: This answer helped me. In my case I had `PaintComponent` instead of `paintComponent` for the method name. Should start with small letter - `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`